# Colorized submit button after html form validation with parsley.js

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, parsley.js

I am using Parsley.js for validating my Bootstrap formatted HTML forms. It works pretty fine. What I want to do now is to change the color for the submit button if validation fails.

I read the documentation from Parsley.js, but I could not find something like adding a class to the submit button, depending on validation.

Example:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="fehler" name="fehler" required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

After click (and validation) should it change to something like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default novalid"></button>
```

or this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Put an ID on your button like "validateFormButton" and create this method to call after sending your form :

```
function change_class(formIsValid) {

var btn = document.getElementById("validateFormButton");
if(formIsValid)
    btn.className= "btn btn-default novalid";
else
    btn.className= "btn btn-danger";
}
```